# Добавить класс в элементу, если URL содержит ?param=

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть - нужно показать Popup, если показывается страница вида myurl.com/?success=1,
где 1 - случайное число.
Если URL содержит "?success=", необходимо добавить класс к элементу. Я так понимаю, надо составить некое регулярное выражение, но на этом познания заканчиваются. Как правильно составить это выражение, используя jQuery?

Comment: Так хэш [ https://google.com/#IAmAHash ] или параметр [ https://google.com/?key=value ]?

Comment: Извиняюсь за неграмотность. В таком случае, видмо, параметр. Ссылка выглядит так, как я описал

Comment: дак и добавьте на серверной стороне при генерации html то?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let params = '?success=1&other=params';
// Настоящие параметры можно взять в location.search

$(_ => {
  if(params.includes('success=1')){
    console.info('Yeah, opening the popup!');
    $('#popup').removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
  }
});
```

```css
.closed:after{
  content: attr(data-close);
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightcoral;
}
.opened:after{
  content: attr(data-open);
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='popup' data-open='Open' data-close='Close' class='closed'></div>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что параметр генерируется плагином Wordpress, я не смогу найти, как и где именно

Comment: Хотите чтобы я Вам ещё и плагин поправил? Демоверсия помощи на это не распространяется :)

Comment: нет, конечно. Можно ли обойтись без настоящих параметров? в строке let params

Comment: @ИванmalginovdesignМальгинов, я же написал что это для примера. Надо брать из `location.search`, там настоящие параметры будут.

Comment: что за location.search?

Comment: @ИванmalginovdesignМальгинов, `location` - объект навигации, его свойство `search` содержит параметры из `URI`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обойти без регулярок, это решение легко адаптировать под свои задачи

```
$('a').each(function(){
  var json = getJsonFromUrl(this);
  if(json.success) {
    $(this)
    .addClass('super-class') //добавить какой-то класс
    .click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); //отменить переход по ссылке
      //todo добавить код открывающий модалку
    });
  }
});

/** функция вернет параметры ссылки в виде json */
function getJsonFromUrl(a) {
  var query = a.search.substr(1);
  var result = {};
  query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
    var item = part.split("=");
    result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/wgLKXy?editors=1010

Comment: модалка открывается имеено классом, но, все же, выглядит рабоче. Завтра попробую